Having trouble finding Pivot index
I am trying to get the pivot index of the given array using python in leetcode.
for the Given an array of integers nums, calculate the pivot index of this array.
This is the code i've used
class Solution:
    def pivotIndex(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        if 1 <= len(nums) <= 104:
            counter1 = 0
            for i in range(len(nums)):
                if -1000 <= nums[i] <= 1000:
                    counter1 += nums[i]
                    counter2 = 0
                    for j in range(i,len(nums)):
                        counter2+=nums[j]
                    if counter1 == counter2:
                        return i
                else:
                    return -1
        return -1
            

It works with most usecases but i don't understand why it is not working in this specific usecase.
this is my submission ( the usecase is present there too) can anyone explain me what i did wrong?

What is the usecase that fails? Can you step through that usecase with a debugger to find out what's going on?

You're checking for the length of the input list being between 1 and 104, but the problem specifies the maximum length as 10 to the power of 4, or 10,000. You are thus returning -1 when the length is greater than 104 without attempting to solve the test case at all.
So, it should be
if 1 <= len(nums) <= 10000:

The input for these problems are guaranteed to be valid and conform to the problem specification, so you can also remove the superfluous checks.
Note that this problem can be solved much faster (in linear time), by precomputing prefix and suffix sums.

It works but as you told it is showing time limit exceeded but all testcases passed.
I read about precomputing the prefix sums, But i couldn't understand it , can you share me some resources on how it works

@Ray Your code should pass if you just remove all the unnecessary bounds checks.

@Ray Here is a solution using suffix sums.

After i read your code i understood where i went wrong. Thanks for the help.
